# Scoped variables in Java. How to link two variables within one scope?

Tags: java, servlets, scope

I am trying to call a variable that is stored as a session scoped variable. If I run the first `if` statement the scoped variable call works. When I run the `else` statement and only enter a name and no address (but a previously entered name with a stored address), the address matching this name isn't returned. Any help would be appreciated because I'm a bit lost with this. Thanks

```
@WebServlet("/Test2") // tells server under which URL to offer this servlet 
public class UserRegistration extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        // set content-type header before accessing the Writer 
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        // then write the response 
        out.println("<html>" + "<head><title>Online Shopping Directory</title></head>");
        //Get the identifier of the book to display 

        out.println("<body bgcolor=\"#ffffff\">"
                + "<h2>Please enter your name:</h2>" + "<form method=\"get\">"
                + "<input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" size=\"25\">"
                + "<p></p>"
                + "<h2>Please enter your address:</h2>" + "<form method=\"get\">"
                + "<input type=\"text\" name=\"useraddress\" size=\"25\">"
                + "<p></p>"
                + "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">"
                + "<input type=\"reset\" value=\"Reset\">"
                + "</form>");

        String name = request.getParameter("username");
        String address = request.getParameter("useraddress");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("username", address);

        if ((name != null) && (name.length() > 0) && (address != null) && (address.length() > 0)) {

            out.println("The username " + name + " has been saved for "
                    + "this session. The address of this user is "
                    + (String) session.getAttribute("username"));
        } else if ((name == "username") && (address == null)) {
            out.println("The username " + name + " is already saved. The address of this user is " + (String) session.getAttribute("username"));
        }
        out.println("</body></html>");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly, and explain what the code should do and what it does instead. What I can say for sure is that `name=="username"`is inccorrect: you compare strings with equals(), not with ==.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I'm new to this site and thought I had uploaded the code correctly. Here is the problem I'm having. Sorry that I wasn't that clear the first time. If a few names and addresses are entered and saved for the session, and then I just enter a name (that has previously been stored with an address) but don't enter an address, then I want the program to call the stored address associated with that name. That is what I'm trying to achieve in the else statement.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should use equals rather ==

```
 if ((name.equals("username")) && (address.equals(""))) {
        out.println("The username " + name + " is already saved. The address of this user is " + (String) session.getAttribute("username"));
    }
```